# python number prediction based on historical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

i need the help the suitable algorithms and code in python, the data table name is Top_10k. 10k roll number (0 to 9999)and the teachers name is stored in this Top_10k table

1)A every day teachers training contacted EDU department in subject wise like Mathematics,Physics,Chemistry,Botany,Zoology,commerce,and Economics. Sunday to Saturday

```
weekly training - 18 teachers 
5day training-10 teachers
4day training-35 teachers
3day training-70 teachers
2day training-35 teachers
1day training 100 teachers
```

the table structure is

```
Serial_no,Selected_Rollno,Subject,Training_date,Training_duration
```

data structure model is

```
1,3124,Physics,22/03/2023,weekly
```

this type historical data we are having CSV files

how to find given date future date data?

for example we need 01/07/2023 date weekly training data 18 teaches roll number

which one algorithm is suitable and how to write the python code?

please help me

i am not try. now i am learning python code

Comment: This is not a homework service.  You must made a good attempt yourself, and then come to us if it doesn't work.

Comment: thank you sir but! i don't have the idea about this? and which one algorithm is suitable for this? thats why  i am asking. you know about the algorithm? tell me the algorithm name. i will try it my self. thank you sir

Comment: I understand, but that's not what this web site is for.  You need to know WHAT to do before you ask HOW to do it.  If you don't know how you would solve this problem as a human, then you can't teach a computer to do it.